# Setup ELK and golang local with docker

Tags: docker, go, elasticsearch, logging, elk

i just wanna know, if you guys have a tutorial to a golang app send logs to elasticsearch with docker

i wanna to send my logs with tcp connection (with logstash or filebeat)

i will be very happy with the recommendation. Tks!

Comment: You can use `filebeat` or `fluend` to collect logs then send to logstash.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably this could help. at least u would get some idea how the log stash config could look like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143576/sending-data-to-logstash-via-tcp